# Edit object while rendering

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to edit your project while im rendering an image in blender 2.83 while but net affecting what im rendering

Comment: why don't you use a cloud machine to render your work?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to edit one object in the scene then for simplicity and safety I'd move that object to its own file, make a backup of that file, and link it into the overall scene file. Then start the render of the scene file from the command line and in a regular Blender instance edit the object in its own file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open two instances of Blender
2. Open the same file
3. Edit the file (on Blender instance 1), save it, launch the render
4. Revert the file (on Blender instance 2), edit and save it
5. When render is complete, you can revert the file of Blender instance
   1

Comment: Beware that this can easily lead to data loss, if you accidentally save on instance 1 after closing instance 2 it will overwrite your work with an older version and no easy way to go back. While it is a useful tip, this should be used with care to avoid loosing work.

Comment: indeed, that is not 100% safe

Comment: I strongly suggest using git together with blender. You will never lose anything.

Comment: Tell us more about git and blender